# Launch4j - no main manifest attribute

Tags: netbeans, launch4j

I made a desktop application using netbeans version 6 and after that converted the jar file into exe file using launch4J. But it gives me the error "no main manifest attribute".
Please help me in finding a solution.
And also How I will specify jre version in launch 4j?

Comment: Can you try running the jar from console by typing java -jar myJarName.jar? Do you get an error or not? What is the contents of your META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, especially the values of 'Main-Class' and 'Rsrc-Main-Class'. Is it set?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second question:

You can not specify the JRE version in generated .exe. The version is set in system environment variables of Windows of the machine running the executable.

What you can do is specify the min and max JRE versions which can be used to run your program.

To set min version, navigate to tab 'JRE' in Launch4j and write '1.8.0' to Min JRE version. If you want another version, replace the text with corresponding version.